# Is it possible to linearise (approximate by a linear function) $y^2=\frac{g}{x} + bx$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linearization

Can you linearise an equationlike $y^2=\frac{g}{x} + bx$? If so, how?

EDIT: g and b are constants

Comment: You need to specify what are $g$ and $b$ and what you mean by "linearise".

Comment: You mean approximating it by a linear function at some point?

Comment: @mvw yes, sorry if I didn’t explain myself clearly in the question :)

Comment: Linearize near what point? That's what the tangent line is for.

Comment: Usually you  look for a line with minimal error rate - measured by distance of the equation points from the line.